# Linkedin API 403 error

Tags: api, permissions, linkedin-api

I want to use the *Linkedin API* to get the company update feeds. I created the app and gave it full permissions. But I got a 403 error

> Member does not have permission to get company.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added `rw_company_admin` to the scope param when you make your authorization request?

Comment: yes, I gave all scopes( r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin, w_share).